$l_\infty(\mathbb Q )$ isn't complete
I am trying to prove that $l_\infty(\mathbb Q )$ isn't complete. When
$$ l_\infty(\mathbb Q ) = \{\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N} \subset \mathbb Q : \sup_k \| x_k \| < \infty \}$$
So I tried to find a cauchy sequence in $ l_\infty(\mathbb Q )$ that isn't convergence in $ l_\infty(\mathbb Q )$
I tried this sequence
$$x^n = \{{x_k}^n\}= \{ (1+\frac{1}{n})^n,(1+\frac{2}{n})^n, (1+\frac{3}{n})^n,...,(1+\frac{k}{n})^n,...\}$$
$\forall k \in \mathbb N,{x_k}^n \to e^k  $ So we can see that
If $y=\{e^k\}_k\in \mathbb N \Rightarrow y\notin l_\infty(\mathbb Q )$ But $\{{x_k}^n\} \to y \text {  } (n\to \infty )$
But I have problem with proving that $ x^n \in l_\infty(\mathbb Q ) $ and proving that $x^n$ is a cauchy sequence.
Any help ?

Let $r_n \in \mathbb Q$ converge to $\sqrt 2$. Then $(r_n,0,0,...)$ is Cauchy sequence which does not converge.

$(\mathbb Q, | \cdot |)$ is naturally embedded in $\ell^{\infty}$. Im sure you can find an easy CS in $\mathbb Q$ and use this as a counterexample.

I got it. Thank you

As pointed out in the comments, just embed your favourite cauchy sequence from $\mathbb Q$ that converges to an irrational number into a fixed coordinate in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb Q)$ to show that it cannot be complete.
To move on to your idea, it won't work. As you point out, for any $k\in\mathbb N$, $x_k^n$ converges to $e^k$, which makes your pointwise limit $y$ unbounded. This means that it not being contained in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb Q)$ may have nothing to do with the irrationality of the entries. This should also suggest to you why you are struggling to prove anything else about your sequence, because none of the $x^n$'s are bounded, so none of them are even in $\ell^\infty(\mathbb Q)$! For any $n\in \mathbb N$, if we choose $k> Mn$ for any $M\in \mathbb N$, then $|x^n_k|>M+1$, so
$$\sup_k|x^n_k|=\infty,$$
meaning $x^n\notin\ell^\infty(\mathbb Q)$. This sequence thus provides you no information about limits in your space.

$x^n$ is a sequence in $l_\infty (\mathbb Q) $ it is not an element in $l_\infty (\mathbb Q) $. for proving that I have to prove that for any fix $k \in \mathbb N $  By the convergence of ${(1+\frac{k}{n})^n}$ this sequence is a bounded sequence so it is an element of $l_\infty (\mathbb Q) $. isn't it true?

@A12345 What you have written, each $x^n$ is a sequence of real numbers, so the only way to interpret it is as an element of a sequence. Recall that an element of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb Q)$ is a bounded sequence. The collection $(x^n)$ is a sequence in a sequence space, but each $x^n$ itself is a sequence, so an element in the sequence space.

@A12345 Yes $lim_{n\to\infty} (1+k/n)^n=e^k$, but this just shows that each coordinate in your limit $y$ (which remember is a sequence of numbers) is a real number. However, $y$ is not bounded in the sup norm, because for each $k$, $y_k=e^k$, and $e^k\to\infty$. Remember that the elements of your sequence are sequences themselves indexed by $k$!

Sorry, I am a little confused because of these indexes. I just saw a video about proving that $l_\infty $ is complete over $\mathbb R$ in that proof he takes the limit sequence in a different way. here I take the limits of the sequence directly but in the proof he takes the limit for the first terms of theses sequences then for the second terms of theses sequences ... So if $ {y}= (y_1,y_2,y_3,...) $ then for example $y_1$ will be like this : $y_1= lim ( (1+\frac{1}{1})^1 ,  (1+\frac{2}{1})^1,  (1+\frac{3}{1})^1, ...,  (1+\frac{k}{1})^1,...)$. is that true?

@A12345 No that is not true. As I said before, each element of your sequence indexed by $n$ is a sequence indexed by $k$. Taking a limit there makes no sense. Is $y$ supposed to be your limit in $\ell^\infty$? I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

I got it. Thank you
